# jquery, get the "upper closest" reference from a no direct sibling

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

look at this structure:

i need to get the "upper closest" hidden input reference from wherever i click

pay attention:

- the starting point (where i click) and the target are not direct siblings
- i can't use unique or composite atrributes

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <input type="hidden" />       //hidden 1
    </th>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 1 from here
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 1 from here
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 1 from here
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 1 from here
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        <input type="hidden" />       //hidden 2
    </th>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 2 from here
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">     //get reference to hidden 2 from here
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 2 from here
    </th>
</tr>
....
```

Comment: In what way is it "closest"? Isn't hidden 2 closer to the 4th `search`, since it's only 1 row away rather than 3 rows for hidden 1?

Comment: @barmar you're right but i specified "upper closest", i'm not sure if upper in this case is the suitable term, anyway i mean the closest that comes "before"

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the closest `input` in the current row and its previous siblings.

```js
function search(el) {
 $(el).closest("tr").add($(el).closest("tr").prevAll("tr")).find("input").last().css("border-color", "red");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="text"/> //hidden 1
    </th>
    <th>
      <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 1 from here
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 1 from here
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 1 from here
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 1 from here
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
        <input type="text"/>       //hidden 2
    </th>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 2 from here
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">     //get reference to hidden 2 from here
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
        <i onclick="search(this)">    //get reference to hidden 2 from here
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not in the `current row`, sometime a row  contains the input, somethime don't, in this case i've look for into some previous rows

Comment: I know. I said "current row and its previous siblings". That's what the `.prevAll()` is for.